# Mule with redis

Tags: redis, mule

I am trying to use Redis connector in Mule, but when I start the application it gives the below error

```
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/redis/current/mule-redis.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>
```

I checked the URL, and it is giving 404 error. I tried replacing current with 3.2, but no luck.

Do anybody have idea, how can we make it running ?

Comment: The schema will be located in the module. Is the redis module on the classpath?

Comment: @RyanCarter, I installed in Mule studio as any other component and I added in my flow. Is there anything else I need to do ?